# Choose default file onchange JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I got a HTML file which just asks to choose a XML file onchange
How can I change this to choose a single file on default

```
<form id='fileSelection' action="">
<center>
<input type='file' id='ipfile'
name='selectedFileName'
accept='text/xml'                     
onchange='javascript:selectXmlFile();'>
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: setting a file by defaut is an impossible thing, because it having some security risk

Answer (score 0):

You can put your default file in the `value` property of the input:

```
<input type="file" value="defaultpath/defaultfile.xml">
```

Comment: Now there is no return from the call... onchange using a funtion..adding it below..hope you can help me in getting details from this below..

    function selectXmlFile(){
    try {
    var form = $('fileSelection');
    var input = form['selectedFileName'];
    GL_params[ID_CMD] = $F(input);
    var filename = $F(input);
    var filetype = filename.endsWith(CMD_XML);